# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am deploying a report in SSRS 2008.

I created the report on the same server as where it should be deployed on.

I am getting this error message when I try to deploy my solution:

```
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
```

why does it use this user? is it logging into the database with this?

thanks so much for you guidance and ttime. and please let me know what information you need in order to point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- SSRS Server uses data sources to connect to databases.
- When you setup a datasource in the SSRS server, under credentials: set the user and
  password.
- When you deploy the report to the SSRS server. In the server you need
  to assign the correct datasource per report

If this is a login problem with the SSRS Web Site, then check the setup. [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839480%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks so much for your help! i used WINDOWS AUTHENTICATION for this because i am able to login to the server with win authent

Comment: when i run these reports directly from the server there are no issues

Comment: the link you gave me is for 2005, i have 2008

Comment: How are you uploading the report? Using a web browser or directly from visual studio?

Comment: im just using DEPLOY from SSRS

Comment: btw i have also added NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON to all databases as  OWNER

Comment: Adding NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON to all databases as OWNER is a major security breach. YOU SHOULD NEVER DO THAT!!!!

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio to build the report?

Comment: Do you know how to login into the SSRS Report Web Server? Something like http://SSRSwebserver.local/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11760/discussion-between---and-internet-engineer)

Comment: I sent you a chat. Did you get it?